# Pass commandline arguments to dll when the dll is an argument to an exe

Tags: c#, dll, command-line-arguments, class-library

I have a C# class library project which produces a dll as output. I need to give commadline arguments to this dll. I have handled the arguments using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() in the class library project code. I need to give this dll as an argument to an exe with class library arguments too. Is it possible? If yes, yow can I achieve this?

This is some what I want to execute in command line.

> $SampleExe.exe "C:\Project\MySampleClassLibrary.dll " "Argument 2 of SampleExe"

Comment: Of course this is possible? You use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` in `SampleExe` as well and voila?

Comment: @GillBates Could you please provide any sample for this?